# How to define the dimension of required Image while calling volley ImageLoader method

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview, android-volley

I am using Volley Library for showing images in `ListView`. As size of images are large, and so cache filled very early.
I am using following method for showing image in List View items:

```
holder.schemeImg.setImageUrl(imgUrl, mImageLoader);
```

Here I initialized Volley `ImageLoader` like this:

```
mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue, new BitmapLruCache(cacheSize));
```

Everything is working fine but I want to resize images before showing them in ImageView.
I have looked into Volley library but not found any method that could do my task.

So, kindly help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to make a different call.

setImageUrl checks the size of your NetworkImageView and resizes it to fit.

However, it only does this if you have explicitly set the size, so wrap_content and fill_parent will not work.

Just take whatever code you were going to use to set the desired size of the image, and set the size of the NetworkImageView before calling setImageUrl

Comment: I have set both width and height of NetworkImageView to 300dp. But when Image display after loading from network is not of 300dp size.

Comment: Could you please show how you are setting the width and height, scale type and a screenshot please.

Answer (score 0):

I defined the size limits in the layout.xml  to limit max size and width of the image in order to display small images in a ListView.

```
<com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
    android:id="@+id/messagePicture"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_gravity="left" />
```

Comment: Problem here is that if you have a lot of NetworkImageViews and you are loading large images (you never know how large the final file is when you load it from the Internet), you may end up with `java.lang.OutOfMemory` exception.